# How much does the nutritional value of insects depend on what they're fed?

Tags: entomology, nutrition

Insects are often touted as being the food of the future due to their nutritional value and small amount of resources required to raise them. However, how dependent is the nutritional value of an insect on what they are consuming. How many vitamins and amino acids are they able to synthesize?